# How to turn neo4j requests to by async using vertx

Tags: asynchronous, neo4j, queue, vert.x

I am using vertx framework.

As we know we cant block the main loop and we willing to use Neo4j.

Nowadays neo4j support on prod only rest and no async support. That could block my main loop on vertx.

so ofoucse I can offload those sync requests to neo4j using vertx worker verticles - but I am expecting thousands of concurrents connections the reason why we choose veryx in first place. Each connection will trigger neo4j and I afraid that neo4j going to be the bottle neck here.

Currently I thought about Two ways:

```
1. Finding a way how to use neo4j asynchronously
2. Send each request to a queue(kafka/etc..) and than send requests to neo4j.
```

What you experts think would be best here?

Thanks,
ray.

Comment: There is also a blog post from Mark Needham how to turn requests to Neo4j into Observables: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/12/28/rxjava-from-future-to-observable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a verticle that spins up an embedded graph database and does async directly.

I've done a spike on a somehow comparable approach using ratpack some time ago: http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2013/09/some-experiments-with-ratpack-and-neo4j/